# ElasticSearch service fails to start on Windows

Tags: java, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch(2.4.6) service is keep failing to start on Windows.

```
[2019-02-01 12:27:59] [info]  [14564] Starting service...
[2019-02-01 12:27:59] [error] [15256] CreateJavaVM Failed
[2019-02-01 12:27:59] [error] [15256] The system cannot find the file specified.
[2019-02-01 12:27:59] [error] [14564] Failed to start Java
[2019-02-01 12:27:59] [error] [14564] ServiceStart returned 4
```

I'm using Java 10, but ElasticSearch 2.4.6 doesn't support Java 9+ so I have set Java 8 JRE's path manually in `elasticsearch.bat` and `service.bat` file.

```
...
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191
...
```

There is no problem while launching ES binary and installing ES as a service, but 'starting' the service is currently impossible.

How to I fix this? I'm also using Haystack, and [it supports only ElasticSearch 1.x and 2.x](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0/backend_support.html#id2), so I can't upgrade the version of ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting JAVA_HOME to jdk path in the system variables.

Comment: I already have Java 10's jdk path. Is it possible to add multiple JAVA_HOME?

Comment: add that in system variables and run the service as administrator

Comment: Before starting elasticsearch.bat in command prompt, try setting java_home using set command.

Comment: I changed JAVA_HOME and entire Java path to JDK 8's directory and now the service works well.

Answer (score 1):

just run /bin/elasticsearch.bat through command line thats it.